# Ubuntu: How to get my data back after sudo rm -r *?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, rm

**Given an user made a clean and successfull:**

```
sudo rm -r * #erase all folders and files recursively starting from root
```

**How to get all the hard drive's data back ?**

Comment: where you working at `/`? Default behavior doesn't expand to `.`-starting filename, you need to set `dotglob` for that http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#dotglob

Comment: Also see section on _Normal behavior_: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs#normal_behaviour

Comment: Easy: restore from your latest backup. You do have one of those, don't you?